# Expansion to first order

Tags: condensed-matter, perturbation-theory

I am working through Altland Simons 2nd edition. From page 221:

> Expansion of $\Pi_{q, \omega_m}\; $ in Eq. (5.30) to first order in $v_F \, q\, / \, w \ll 1$ leads to the expression:
> $$V_{\text{eff}} \,  (q, \omega_m) = \frac{4 \pi e^2}{q^2} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{4 \pi \nu_{\, 0} \; e^2 \,  v_{\, F}^2}{3 \omega_{\, m}^2}} = \frac{4 \pi e^2}{q^2} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2}}, $$

where the plasma frequency is defined $\omega_p \equiv (4 \pi n e^2 \, / \, m)^{1/2}$ and $n \equiv N/L^3 = 2 k_F^3 \, / \, 6 \pi^2$. I don't know how to get either equality for $V_{\text{eff}}$ above and would like more details.

For the first equality, I wanted to use the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series):

$$- \log (1 - z) = z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{3} + \cdots$$

Taking

$$z = \frac{\frac{2 v_{F} \, \, q}{\omega_{\, m}} \left( i + \frac{v_F \, \, q}{\omega_m} \right)}{1 + \frac{v_{\, F}^{\, 2} \, \, q^2}{\omega_{\, m}^{\, 2}}},$$

we get both an imaginary term and a real term, which after multiplication by $i$ in front of ln (see eq 5.30 below), becomes a real term and an imaginary term. This cannot be correct as there is no imaginary term in the desired expression for $V_{\text{eff}}$. Additionally, I end up with a $q^2$ in the denominator of the second term of the denominator (to be canceled out with the $q^2$ in the prefactor $\frac{4 \pi e^2}{q^2}$).

For the second equality, I get that it is just simple substitution of $\omega_p$, but $\omega_p$ is a function of $n$, which is a function of $k_F$. How is $k_F$ related to $v_F$? I can't find the equation connecting $k_F$ and $v_F$ in the text, but maybe I just missed it.

For reference, equation 5.30 is:

> $$\Pi_{q, \omega_m \, } = - \nu_0 \left[ 1 - \frac{i \omega_m}{2 v_F \, q} \, \ln \left( 
> \frac{i \omega_m + v_F \, q}{i \omega_m - v_F \, q} \right) \right],$$

Comment: Isn't it just simply $k_F = p_F/\hbar = mv_F/\hbar$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Any Taylor series expansion in $q$ will work, but it's probably
easier to write
\begin{equation}
\ln(1\pm x) = \pm x -\frac{1}{2}x^2 \pm \frac{1}{3}x^3 -...
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
\ln \left (\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right ) = \ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x) = 2x+\frac{2}{3}x^3 +...
\end{equation}
and then write
\begin{equation}
\ln \left (\frac{i\omega_m+v_F q}{i\omega_m-v_f q}\right)
= \ln \left (\frac{1+\frac{v_Fq}{i\omega_m}}{1-\frac{v_Fq}{i\omega_m}}\right)
= 2\frac{v_Fq}{i\omega_m}
+\frac{2}{3}\left (\frac{v_Fq}{i\omega_m}\right)^3+... \,.
\end{equation}
Substituting into the expression for $\Pi_{q,\omega_m}$ gives
\begin{equation}
\Pi_{q,\omega_m}  = -\nu_0\frac{v_F^2 q^2}{3\omega_m^2} +...
\end{equation}
which is the result for the first equation. Substituting $\omega_m = -i\omega$
for the Matsubara frequencies gives the second with the definition
given by Mathphys meister.